# kafka producer panic

Tags: go, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I'm working on building kafka producer based on golang right now. I cannot sent any message from my producer. The panic shown as follow:

```
producer close, err: kafka: client has run out of available brokers to talk to(Is your cluster reachable?)
```

I test the kafka-console-consumer and kafka-console-producer, they are all work well on terminal. So, is there anything I missed?
Here's the code:

```
package main
import (
    "github.com/Shopify/sarama"
    "log"
    "os"
    "strings"
)

var (
    logger = log.New(os.Stderr, "[srama]", log.LstdFlags)
)

func main() {
    sarama.Logger = logger

    config := sarama.NewConfig()
    config.Producer.Return.Successes = true
    config.Producer.RequiredAcks = sarama.WaitForAll
    config.Producer.Partitioner = sarama.NewRandomPartitioner

    msg := &sarama.ProducerMessage{}
    msg.Topic = "hello"
    msg.Partition = int32(-1)
    msg.Key = sarama.StringEncoder("key")
    msg.Value = sarama.ByteEncoder("hello, world!")

    producer, err := sarama.NewSyncProducer(strings.Split("localhost:9092", ","), config)//default port
    if err != nil {
        logger.Println("Failed to produce message: %s", err)
        os.Exit(500)
    }
    defer producer.Close()

    partition, offset, err := producer.SendMessage(msg)
    if err != nil {
        logger.Println("Failed to produce message: ", err)
    }
    logger.Printf("partition=%d, offset=%d\n", partition, offset)
}
```

Comment: One hint might be to check if producer is not closing before message is sent. Try removing producer.Close() altogether.

Comment: How are you running Kafka and ZooKeeper ? The problem can be you misconfigured address of Kafka brokers in Zookeeper.

Comment: Eh, I already check the address of Kafka and zookeeper,  I only built one broker which id is 0.

Comment: You probably at least want to call `producer.poll()` somewhere in here. I'm not familiar with Golang, but it looks like you try to produce a message and then immediatly exit the program, which is unlikely to work.